# Duda con la formulación de rutas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Buen dia comunidad : Tengo un problema en Laravel que no he podido solucionar.

Creé dos rutas que apuntan al mismo controlador, pero distintas funciones, y cada una de ellas va según la cantidad de variables. Lo tengo configurado de la siguiente forma :

```
Route::middleware('apikey')->group(function() {
    Route::controller(InformesController::class)->group(function() {
        Route::get('/informes/consultaStock/{formato}/{apikey}/{tabla}/{itemCode}', 'consultaStock')->where(['tabla' => '[a-z]+','itemCode' =>'.*']);
        Route::get('/informes/consultaStock/{formato}/{apikey}/{itemCode}','consultaStockGeneral')->where(['itemCode' =>'.*']);
    });
});
```

Sin embargo, al enviar una ruta con los parámetros /html/api/itemCode, sigue entrando a la función "Consulta stock" cuando debiera entrar a "Consulta stock general". He probado cambiando las rutas de orden (Colocar "consultastockgeneral" por sobre "consultastock") pero sigue sin funcionar.

¿Donde puede estar el problema?

Les agradezco la orientación.

Comment: Esto no soluciona tu error pero: AVISO: No envies la apikey como parámetro de URL. Es un fallo de seguridad sinPerdón.

Comment: Solo se me ocurre cambiar el orden... has probado a refrescar la cache? `php artisan optimize`